# Extract Matching group between slashes using sed, grep breaks for special chars

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I want to extract string between two forward slashes with some word e.g. `test` as string start (before the first slash), **but last slash and after content of it is optional**. I am able to extract it correctly but if there is special chars in string I want to extract, it should fail.

```
some_word/part_i_want_to_extract/optional_string
                                ^               
                                | from here is optional (including /)
```

Also part I want extract should only contain alpha numerics, `_` and `-`.

examples for sed:

```
echo 'test/alpha_numeric-9034/something' | sed -r 's|^.*(test)/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/[[:alnum:]]*)?.*$|\2|' // returns alpha_numeric-9034

echo 'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034/something' | sed -r 's|^.*(test)/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/[[:alnum:]]*)?.*$|\2|' // returns alpha_numer

echo 'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034' | sed -r 's|^.*(test)/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/[[:alnum:]]*)?.*$|\2|' // returns alpha_numer
```

I want to second/third to fail (should return nothing), How would I do that?

same examples in grep:

```
echo 'test/alpha_numeric-9034/something' | grep -oP "^(test)\/\K([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?" // returns alpha_numeric-9034

echo 'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034/something' | grep -oP "^(test)\/\K([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?" // returns alpha_numer

echo 'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034' | grep -oP "^(test)\/\K([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?" // returns alpha_numer
```

Also in grep using `$` at end doesn't give anything. [Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/vw81v7/2) which works for php based regex, I couldn't find any working perl tool. Any help would be grateful.

More examples about what should return

```
'test/alpha_numeric-9034/something' -> alpha_numeric-9034
'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034/something' -> should be nothing (since it has $)
'test/alpha_numeric-9034' -> alpha_numeric-9034
'test/QR-9034' -> QR-9034
```

Comment: Is it really always (at most) just two slashes?

Comment: There may be more, as seperators. For the moment I am interested in extracting first string surrounded by forward slashes.

Comment: What precisely do you consider to be "special characters"?

Comment: Those would be !@#$%^&*()+=~`

Comment: Remove `?` off lookahead and do `(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*|$)` instead.

Comment: For sed it would be `sed -r 's~^test/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/|$)~\1~'`

Comment: @revo `echo 'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034' | sed -r 's~^test/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/|$)~\1~'` gives me `test/alpha_numer$ic-9034`, I didn't get the first comment. Although I tried as `sed -r 's|^.*(test)/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(?=/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$).*$|\2|'` is that what you meant?

Comment: Your first command outputs the exact same input string because sed can't match anything. So it works as intended. Sed is a find / replace tool not a *match only* tool.

Comment: You quantified lookahead as in `(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?` (Watch the `?`). It shouldn't be there. Remove it and put `$` in an alternation inside e.g. `(?=\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*|$)`

Comment: Ok got it, thanks a lot. Is there any way to return nothing if sed can't match anything? Also could you please post an answer to accept.

Comment: Updated my answer with a pure bash solution (no external tools needed at all), following the clarification of desired "_in bash with minimal tooling/lang support_"

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan You could work around it like this `echo 'test/alpha_numer$ic-9034/' | sed -r 's~^test/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/|$)|.*~\1~'`. If other answers didn't solve your issue I'll post an answer.

Comment: @revo your last workaround works but misses `'test/alpha_numeric-9034'`, Please if you could, since others are not exact solution but collective.

Comment: Is `'test/alpha_numeric-9034'` a desired match?

Comment: yes it should give me `alpha_numeric-9034`, sorry If question doesn't reflect it. I'll try to update it more elaborately.

Comment: Weird. It should match. I answered with a slightly different solution.

Comment: I'm not clear why you start with using `some_word/...` and continue with `test/...`. Do you want to include the specific word in your regex pattern?

Comment: @Borodin yes `some_word` would be predetermined any word, `test` is just an example

Comment: @Ruwanka: That doesn't help much. How do you want to treat it in your code? Will you accept anything at all before the slash and the field you want, including stuff with slashes and perhaps newlines?

Comment: @Borodin Ok, I want to start the string with word say 'test', yes I am doing something that word but it is not relevant to the problem. So first word is required, first slash is required, then string with alphanumerics and no special chars other than _,-, last slash is optional but if it is there some description should follow it.. Is that helping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add a sed solution however sed wouldn't be a perfect way to go:

```
sed -r 's~^test/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/|$)|.~\1~g'
```

This looks for an input string starting with `test`, following a `/[[:alnum:]_-]*` pattern up to a `/` or end of input string. The other side of alternation is a period which is supposed to match on failure. `g` flag is enabled as well. (I'm not sure why `sed -r 's~^test/([[:alnum:]_-]*)(/|$)|.*~\1~'` didn't work. If someone has a hint he / she is welcome.)

Test cases:

```
$ echo 'test/al_num-0$' | ...

$ echo 'test/al_num-0' | ...
al_num-0
$ echo 'test/al_num-0/something' | ...
al_num-0
```

Comment: Works like charm, What is the perfect way to go? I'm not familiar with bash stuff, hint would be great! As in @zdim answer I thought of using cut and do some ifs, is it a good one?

Comment: Sed is short and so handy but not perfect in the sense that it is a find & replace tool. Perl would be the way to go. Just have it in your environment.

Comment: wrt `If someone has a hint` - the regexp matches the leftmost longest string so when the part after `|` is `.` the part before the `|` is longer and so `\1` is populated but when it's `.*` THAT is always the longest and in that case there is no capture group being populated (since the 2 capture groups are only populated on the left side of the `|`) so `\1` is not populated, hence the blank output lines.

Comment: @EdMorton That's it. However, it's not the regexp that follows the leftmost longest rule. It's the engine.

Comment: I didn't say the regexp did it (I'm not even sure what that would mean), I said the regexp matches and yes, it's the regexp engine that is identifying the leftmost longest string that matches the given regexp.

Comment: The *regexp matches* is so general that it would not be right in other similar contexts. Hence saying *engine* is more tied to this answer.

Comment: Can you every say `the regexp matches the WHATEVER string` without that meaning that the engine interpreting the regexp is selecting the WHATEVER string from the input as a result of performing a match using that regexp? There is no ambiguity in what I said - `the regexp matches the leftmost longest string`. I don't see how it could be interpreted to mean anything other than that the regexp in question is matching the leftmost longest string in the input in question.

Comment: In fact, there is ambiguity. With the *regexp matches the leftmost longest string...* next time that I need to do a task in JS or PCRE or even if I wanted to go with Perl CLI instead of SED / AWK to perform the same exact match, I'll come to this point that *The leftmost longest match, huh?*

Comment: You asked what might be wrong with your script. I told you what is wrong with your script. And you think people will now assume that what I told you is wrong with your script is also true of every other script in every other tool. I'm trying to come up with a real world analogy to help you see how silly that sounds to me, best I can think of is - your car broke down and you asked what's wrong and I said "the gas tank is empty" and people then assume that the gas tank is empty on every car. idk if that really captures it but it's in the ballpark. Anyway - all the best with your programming.

Comment: *"Works like charm"* is probably the *worst* criterion you could apply to a program. Less awful, but still bad, are *"is it fast?"* and *"does it minimise memory?"*. Much more useful are *"do you understand how it works?"*, *"could you alter this to fulfil a slightly different requirement?"*, and *"is it necessary to use several different languages?"*

Comment: @EdMorton I should have thanked you earlier, my bad so thank you. But the helpful note and misused terminology have nothing in common.

Comment: @EdMorton Your example need to change a bit to hold true for this case: Your car broke down and you ask *"What is wrong?"* and I say, *"Your gas tank implements the **leftmost-X** feature but it's running out"*. Later, you decide to pull it off the car and have your beloved gas tank into another car. The same problem occurs and you come to me and ask again *"What is wrong?"* and I say, *"Your gas tank implements the **rightmost-X** feature but it's running out."*. *"Huh?"* you say, *"It's all because of the car"*, I finish.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**   Added a version for the last question edit.

---

With Perl (as tagged), using your echo-ed lines of data in a file `data.txt`

```
perl -wnE'@m = m{^test/([\w-]+)(?=/)}g; say "@m" if @m' data.txt
```

This prints only the `alpha_numeric-9034` from the first line.

I use `[\w-]`, change to go via the [POSIX character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes), `[[:alnum:]_-]`, if you wish. The other option is to list forbidden characters along with `/` in a negated class,
`[^/...]`.

The code captures allowed characters after the `^test/` up to the next `/`, using a positive lookahead to assert that the `/` is there. The lookahead, being a "*zero width assertion*," does not consume that slash, otherwise this would fail with more than two slashes.

Assuming a path as the target the code captures between slashes only when there is something, discarding `//` but still matching the line. If you want the "nothing" between slashes change the `+` quantifier to `*` and you'll get an empty string for that `//` pair.

It also works with any number of slashes, extracting what is in between consecutive ones. Tested by adding a line `test/first/yet/more/end` to the file used above, for

```
alpha_numeric-9034
first yet more
```

---

**Note**   The last question edit allows `test/QR-9034`, so *without* the second slash. That contradicts the original statement and explicit early clarifications and the solutions above (Perl) and below (bash) weren't designed for it and won't work in that case.

However, it is only (much) easier if we can only have at most two slashes

```
perl -wnE'say $1 if m{^test/([\w-]+)/?}' data.txt
```

This matches what follows `^test/` as above, up to the next *optional* (`?`) slash.

---

If this is indeed about parsing paths please use modules that do precisely that.

---

It is clarified that the goal is to do this in bash, with **"minimal tool/lang support"**. Then this can be done directly in bash. That won't be concise as in Perl but no other tools are used. One way

```
#!/bin/bash

string='test/one/two/end'

# Build array of fields using / for the separator
IFS='/' read -ra ary <<< "$string"

# Note: don't know how the presumed bash script is organized
# Use checks below (or alternatives) for flow control you need

# Check for non :alnum: characters. Iterating is a bit slow but clear
for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ [^[:alnum:]] ]]; then
        echo "Element $i has non-alnum"
        has_special=1
        break
    fi  
done

if [[ ${#ary[@]} -le 1 || ${ary[0]} != "test" || $has_special ]]; then
    echo "No match"
else
    # Remove first and last elements
    unset 'ary[${#ary[@]}-1]'
    unset 'ary[${ary[0]}]'

    echo "${ary[@]}"
 fi
```

This prints the line:   `one two`   (or `No match` if the string/`$IFS` is changed so to fail)

All parts of the above can be done in other ways. Comments

- The checks (for non-alnum, `test/`, and overall match) are given simply as it is not specified what flow control is suitable. Restructure for nicer program organization
- The iteration used to check array elements is clear but slow; there are other ways. If there is interest in this please let me know and I'll edit. Also, the string itself can be checked but then we can't (simply) use `:alnum:` since it *does* contain `/`
- The `read` is practically the most efficient way to break a string by separators into an array, with no forks or external tools or resources
- On newer bash (4.3+ ?) you can just do `unset 'array[-1]'` etc
- In recent bash the above changes `$IFS` only within the current command
- If there was no match the whole string is in the first element of `ary`, so I check size

Comment: I tagged it as perl since `grep -P` is used, Thanks for the idea of using path parsing tools, this is not path related but It could help. Would you be able to give me sample in grep or sed. I am trying to do this in bash with minimal tooling/lang support.

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan  Added to the answer a way to do this directly in bash, what should be optimal according to your comment

Comment: Your vanila bash solution doesn't check if string starts with `test`.

Comment: @revo It discards what precedes the first slash, which is the requirement, I think. This is also easily adjusted.  I don't understand why the string would start with `test` ?

Comment: @zdim Acctually first one should be test or some word, it is a requirement which I missed in my question. Sorry for inconvenience and I'll update it to reflect.

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan Added test for whether the string starts with `test/`, and added a test of whether it matched to the bash example.  I don't know what flow control you need in the script, please adjust for that if it isn't what I used as an example.

Comment: @revo Just how did you know that it need start with a specific string? :)  Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I picked @revo's one because of question is about sed, but this is another way of solving the problem.

Comment: I just looked at the regular expressions in OP and wondered if `^test` - the caret specially - has no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it clear, simple, efficient, robust, portable, etc. and just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'/' '($1=="test") && ($2~/^[[:alnum:]_-]+$/){print $2}' file
alpha_numeric-9034
alpha_numeric-9034
QR-9034
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{print (($1=="test") && ($2~/^[[:alnum:]_-]+$/) ? $2 : "")}' file
alpha_numeric-9034

alpha_numeric-9034
QR-9034
```

depending on if you want nothing or a blank line output given non-matching input.

Comment: I can't help but ask: is this more "_clear, simple, efficient, robust, portable_" than the short(er) Perl line?  Any one of it?  I am only commenting on "_just use awk_". Why not, say, "_with awk_" instead?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it is. perl isn't installed on all UNIX machines while awk is hence portability. Anyone can see exactly what the awk script does whereas the perl script is a convoluted mess of arcane single-char options and instructions hence clarity and simplicity. awk is doing a string comparison plus small trivial regexp comparison using a non-PCRE engine hence efficiency. I don't have perl on my box to test with but it looks like it'd need rework if "test" contained RE metachars plus the `$` needs to be replaced hence robustness. I listed the benefits because the OP may not realize them.

Comment: Wow. I disagree with just about all of that, except indeed with portability. (I never timed them either but that can only be about tens of milliseconds, irrelevant in a one-liner.)  OK, I respect your opinion and surely didn't mean to attack your post (I didn't realize that you meant all that, actually.) I'll gladly remove the comment if you wish.  Note that it can be almost the same in Perl as yours, but the one I posted catches things between any number of `/` pairs.  (It doesn't with just one `/` (not a pair), what was added as a requirement later.)

Comment: I understand that somehow people get used to it and manage to memorize all the single character perl instructions and syntax but the reality is that no-one creates cartoons like https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13 about awk syntax and you might want to read https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html about perls regexp execution speed. I know people CAN write legible perl but for some reason they don't and instead idiomatic perl apparently favors brevity at the cost of everything else. I'm fine whether you leave your comment or not - whatever you prefer.

Comment: Well, Perl's a tool like any other, with its rules and the good and the bad.  And it's a very different kind of a tool from awk.  I don't know what you refer to with "_single character instructions_" -- the one-liner's flags? I can accept those given that they avail me the power tool like Perl in a one-line program (not that I like those!).

Comment: Yes. `perl -wnE'@m = m{...` - you've got to admit that's pretty darn obscure! 3 more consonants and the batman symbol and it might summon Cthulhu! I'm not asking for an explanation just pointing out that its intent, caveats, etc. are far from obvious.

Comment: Yes, one can definitely write Perl that's easy to read (once readers can swallow the sigils); I have a hard-core Python developer at work (who knows no Perl) who reads my modules written for his server, with very little help. But I'm OK with conciseness as well, if it's well crafted and comes with a well designed interface; becomes a little in-line library. As for regex, I consider it a feature that it is so well integrated in the language.  Like the addition of thread support to  C++  -- now I only use that, even as it is far from perfect.

Comment: One-liner switches -- sure, one has to _know_ what those are for.  But isn't it like that with any language?  I recall my first look at the "clear and beautiful" Python -- couldn't follow _anything_, and I did have some half a dozen or so languages/tools under my belt by then. (I like Python, again, it's a useful tool.)

Comment: wrt `I'm OK with conciseness as well` - everyone is, conciseness is a common goal when writing software. My point is that perl code is not concise, it's just brief. Perl has a million bells and whistles to encourage users to write brief code, most often at the expense of clarity. Awk deliberately, by design, does not have all those bells and whistles so the resulting code even when brief is still usually clear, i.e. it is concise. Anyway, this debates been had a million times, no-ones going to change their opinion on any of it.

Comment: "_this debates been had a million times_" -- yes, and yes for what you say for Perl. I accept it as it is, with its good and bad. I indeed won't change my opinion suddenly (I've been staring at all you say for years) but It's good to be reminded of the whole context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F\/ 'NF>2 && $2 ~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$/ {print $2}'
alpha_numeric-9034
```

Or this:

```
awk -F\/ 'NF>2 && $2 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_-]+$/ {print $2}'
alpha_numeric-9034
```

Or this:

```
awk -F\/ 'NF>2 && $2 !~ /[!@#$%^&*()+=~]/ {print $2}'
alpha_numeric-9034
```

It test if there are minimum 2 `/` and print the first data between `//` if it contains the correct value
PS I would say that `-` and `_` is special chars

Comment: This works great for optional /something is present,  without it for an example test/alpha_numeric-9034 any of these returns nothing. I am I missing something here?

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan It counts the number of field separated by /, if its only two filed (one /) do not print, it need to be minimum 3 field (two /), then it prints second field if it is in correct format.

Comment: Ok but I am also interested in scenario where there can be only two fields as per updated question

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan Just change `NF>2` to `NF>1`